# How to change\swap multiple CSS files on user-input in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var 
defcore = '...core.css',
altcore = '...core-dark.css',
defcomponent = '...components.css',
altcomponent = '...components-dark.css',
hrefAttr;

$('#css_toggle').click(function () {
  $('link').each(function(){
    hrefAttr = $(this).attr('href');
    
    if (hrefAttr.indexOf(defcore)>= 0) 
    {
      $(this).attr('href', altcore);
      localStorage.setItem('mode', 'dark');     
    } 


    else if (hrefAttr.indexOf(altcore) >= 0) {
      $(this).attr('href', defcore);
      localStorage.setItem('mode', 'light');  
    }

  });
});
</script>
```

I'm working on a project where I have to change the theme mode of the project. I have respectively created two CSS files (core & components) and (core-dark & components-dark) one for the light mode and the other for dark mode. On User input the CSS files are suppose to change. However, my code is working fine for the swap between core  & core-dark but I'm unable to include the other files.

I tired the following but it didn't work:

```
$('#css_toggle').click(function () {
  $('link').each(function(){
    hrefAttr = $(this).attr('href');
    
    if (hrefAttr.indexOf(defcore)>= 0) 
    {
      $(this).attr('href', altcore);
      $(this).attr('href', altcomponent);
      localStorage.setItem('mode', 'dark');     
    }
```

Comment: Didn't quite understand the question ... Do you need conditional loading of css files?

Comment: Yes, I have 2 CSS files that I want to replace with other 2 CSS files. I have tried the above mentioned method but it works for only single file not the second one. Don't know what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Your problem is that you are using the `this` selector, which means that one file overlaps the other. Those. - overlap. Let me give me some free time and I will try to help you.

Comment: I have a question regarding `localStorage.setItem('mode', 'light')`; ... Where do you declare the variable `'light'`, and why is this variable in parentheses? I think that if it was like this - `var light = ...`, then the expression should be like this - `localStorage.setItem('mode', light);`

Comment: It might be because of the selector. I don't know how to implement it properly yet.

However, the local storage part is for something else. It's there to store the changed CSS file updates while it navigates through other HTML pages of the system.

Comment: try my solution please